# Facebook not returning User Data in some cases for OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-login

When I am requesting User Data from Facebook using a proper app id and app secret from the Facebook API, then in some cases it is providing all the data that is required like Firstname, Lastname, email and Gender.

But for some of my websites the no data is returned from the Facebook API which creates an error and the customer is not able to login to the store through Facebook.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found and fixed the issue just by adding the fields name that are required to login.

I have replaced this line:

```
$client->CallAPI('https://graph.facebook.com/me', 'GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
```

with this line

```
$client->CallAPI('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=email,first_name,other', 'GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
```

And now my facebook login is working like charm.

To know other fields that can be fetched you can visit [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour: some data the user can choose not to divulge when he authorises your app on Facebook. Your backend need to handle those cases correctly: by choosing default data for the user or by returning an error and the option to try again (using auth_type re-request : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2#re-asking-declined-permissions )

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the same user is able to login to one website but not to other as the data is not returned. I have personally tested it using my facebook account but the same problem persist.

Comment: for the email, the user can choose not to divulge it, even you asked for it. If you can find two API calls with the same permissions that return different results for different API keys, you should submit a bug to Facebook, it's likely to be a problem on their side